# Threejs and WebGL not rendering 3d objects in firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, three.js, webgl

Hello everyone I am creating my own website using reactjs and I want to include 3d object in my website.
To do that I am using three js with a WebGL renderer, it usually works fine but SOMETIMES my 3d object does not render and I get a black frame instead (see the pictures). Now the issue is that this bug happens sometimes and I can't understand what produces it. The bug is only happening on firefox, chrome works fine.

[3d object bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEnRG.png)

[3d object working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xgDl.png)

I know how to solve it for my computer (I have to enable graphic performances for firefox in config panel), yet it was working perfectly fine sometimes without graphic performances enabled. My fear is that if I deploy my website this bug occurs for other user.

**(Edit after some research this is EXACTLY the issue https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1712486 but i don't get how to solve the issue)**

I am pretty sure that this is due to the WebGL renderer which seems to sometimes have trouble to load textures with my graphic card... not sure why.

Can anyone help me to find a fix (for every user not only for my computer) or is there a way to check if this rendering bug happens in order to display an image instead ?

Here is the code to generate my object :

```js
import React from 'react';
import './object3d.css';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { RGBELoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/RGBELoader.js';
var sat;

function loadGLTFModel(scene, glbPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    const loader = new RGBELoader();
    //loader.load(
    loader.load( 'royal_esplanade_1k.hdr', ( texture ) => {

      texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;

      scene.environment = texture;

      const loader2 = new GLTFLoader();
      loader2.load( glbPath, function ( gltf ) {
        sat = gltf.scene
        scene.add( sat );
        resolve(sat);

      } );

  },
  undefined,
  function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    reject(error);
  } );
  });
}

const Object = ({path_file}) => {
  const refContainer = useRef();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [renderer, setRenderer] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current: container } = refContainer;
    if (container && !renderer) {
      const scW = container.clientWidth;
      const scH = container.clientHeight;
      //console.log(scW);
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true,
        premultipliedAlpha : false
      });
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(scW, scH);
      renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      setRenderer(renderer);

      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const scale = 25;
      const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
        -scale,
        scale,
        scale,
        -scale,
        0.01,
        50000
      );
      camera.position.y = 25;
      camera.position.x = 2;
      camera.position.z = 0;
      camera.rotation.y = 45* Math.PI /180;
      camera.rotation.z = 45* Math.PI /180;
      const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 1);
      scene.add(ambientLight);
      
      loadGLTFModel(scene, path_file, {
      }).then((sat) => {
        animate(sat);
        setLoading(false);
      });

      let req = null;
      const animate = () => {
        req = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        sat.rotation.y+=0.01;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      return () => {
        cancelAnimationFrame(req);
        renderer.dispose();
      };
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='container_3d'
      ref={refContainer}
    >
      {loading && (
        <span style={{ left: "50%", top: "50%" }}>
          Loading...
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};


const Object3dsat = ({path_file}) => {
  return (
    <Object path_file={path_file}/>
  )
}

export default Object3dsat
```

I notted that when the bug occurs I got multiple lines in the Fail Logs :

*"RenderDXGITextureHost Failed to open shared texture, hr=0x80070057"*

More Over my config :
GPU 1 : AMD radeon RX Vega 10

GPU 2 : Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060

CPU : AMD Ryzen 7 3750H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx

and I am using Firefox Version: 105.0.1
(I also notted that the GPU used for Web rendering is the AMD Radeon GPU but it was working even with this GPU)

Hope you guys can help me
Thank you for your help !